# Unable to access MongoDB within a container within a Docker Machine instance from Windows

Tags: windows, mongodb, docker, virtual-machine, docker-machine

I am running Windows 7 on my desktop at work and I am signed in to a regular user account on the VPN. To develop software, we are to normally open a Dev VM and work from in there however recently I've been assigned a task to research Docker and Mongo DB. I have very limited access to what I can install on the main machine.

Here lies my problem:

Is it possible for me to connect to a MongoDB instance inside a container inside the docker machine from Windows and make changes? I would ideally like to use a GUI tool such as Mongo Management Studio to make changes to a Mongo database within a container.

By inspecting the Mongo container, it has the ports listed as: 0.0.0.0:32768 -> 27017/tcp 
and docker-machine ip (vm name) returns 192.168.99.111.

I have commented out the 127.0.0.1 binding host ip within the mongod.conf file also.

From what I have researched so far, most users resolve their problem by connecting to their docker-machine IP with the port they've set with -p or been given with -P. Unfortunately for me, trying to connect with 192.168.99.111:32768 does not work.

I am pretty stumped and quite new to this environment. I am able to get inside the container with bash and manipulate the database there however I'm wondering if I can do this within Windows.

Thank you if anyone can help.

Comment: Can you ping `192.168.99.111` from your Windows machine to make sure you can see/access the container at all?

Comment: Pinging causes the requests to time out and the 4 packets sent to be lost giving 100% loss. What could be causing this do you think?

Comment: Perhaps missing DNS entries, but try to search for yourself - the keyword is "accessing a docker machine from the host" which is a common problem on many occasions.

Comment: Thanks for the help, pinging and receiving no packets caused me to search for an alternate IP. It turns out using the docker-machine IP was not the way forward for my case but instead the IP listed under Eth0 from ifconfig within the VM.

Comment: Can you paste your docker file and container start script/command?

Comment: The dockerfile can be found at https://hub.docker.com/r/babakmomen/dockermongoautomatedbuild/~/dockerfile/. and the start command was "docker start trusting_saha". 
The container was created from: docker run -P -d babakmomen/dockermongoautomatedbuild

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading Smutje's advice to ping the VM IP and testing it out to no avail, I attempted to find a pingable IP which would hopefully move me closer to my goal.

By doing "ifconfig" within the Boot2Docker VM (but not inside the container), I was able to locate another IP listed under eth0. This IP looks something like 134.36.xxx.xxx to me and is pingable. With the Mongo container running I can now access the database from within Mongo Management Studio by connecting to 134.36.xxx.xxx:32768 and manipulate the data from there.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the option of choosing the operating system for your dev VM, go with Ubuntu and setup docker with all of the the containers you want to test on that. Either way, you will need to have a VM for testing docker on windows since it uses VirtualBox if i'm not mistaken. Instead, setup an Ubuntu VM and do all of your testing on that.